# C#. Создание нормализованного вектора в указанном направлении

Tags: c#, линейная-алгебра

Решил побаловаться RayCast'ом, написал классы Ray и Boundary, которые представляют луч и препятствие соответственно. После занялся формоблудством, накидал контролы на форму. В чём суть. При нажатии кнопки на форме `Старт`, создаётся указанное кол-во лучей, с углом, на который они должны быть смещены. Например, если заданно 6 лучей, то они должны быть сдвинуты на 0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300 градусов соответственно. Но, что-то пошло не так. Вопрос: что не так, и что нужно, чтоб было так?

Создание лучей

```
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
{
    rays.Add(new Ray(new Point(350, 210), (360 / (float)numericUpDown1.Value) * i));
}
```

В конструкторе класса

```
public Ray(Point point, float angle)
{
    this.pointPos = point;
    //pointDir - вектор направления, исп. вместе с pointPos, где pointPos - позиция (0, 0) для вектора направления. т.е. pointPos смещает центр с 0,0 левого верхнего угла pb на (x,y) в pointPos. pointDir нормализован.
    this.pointDir = new PointF((float)(Math.Cos(180 / Math.PI * angle) - Math.Sin(180 / Math.PI * angle)), (float)(Math.Sin(180 / Math.PI * angle) + Math.Cos(180 / Math.PI * angle)));
    this.pointHit = default;
}
```

[image: 6 лучей]
[image: 12 лучей]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргумент  `Cos/Sin` должен быть в радианах, для этого градусы нужно **умножить** на `Pi`  и разделить на `180`

Comment: Блин, точно, огромное спасибо